# Extreme Values of $x^2-y^2$ constraint to $x^2+y^2=1$

Tags: derivatives, optimization

$f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ constraint to $x^2+y^2=1$

$f_x=2x$ and $f_y=-2y$ $\implies$ the critical point is at $(0,0)$

However, $(0,0)$ does not occur in the constraint. does that mean i don't have to consider it?

So if we work of the boundary curves $y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$

we get a min @ $(0,1)$ with the value $-1$ and a max @ either $(1,0) or (-1,0)$ with the value $1$

did i do it correctly?

Comment: See [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).

Comment: set $$y^2=x^2-1$$ in your $$f(x,y)$$

Answer (score 3):

A bit of an overkill, don't you think? The problem is equivalent to finding the extreme values of $z-(1-z)$, i.e. of a line, subject to the constraint $z\in[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

Given $x^2+y^2 = 1\;,$ Let $x=\cos \phi$ and $y=\sin \phi\;,$ Then $x^2-y^2 = \cos^2 \phi-\sin^2 \phi = \cos 2\phi$

Now Using $\bullet\; -1\leq \cos 2\phi \leq 1$

So we get $x^2-y^2\in \left[-1,1\right]$